# Transfer Lead Records(Fields) to a custom object when converting

Tags: lead-conversion

I am new to salesforce so forgive me if this question is trivial. If it has been previously been answered kindly direct me since I have searched but not found the appropriate solution.
How do you transfer the records in the standard lead object to a custom object that I have created(not the standard contact,account or opportunity).
Description:
My standard lead object has fields like:
Name
Email
Phone
etc.
My custom object also has the same fields and others.
What I want is that when I convert the lead, the fields that are similar i.e Name, Email and Phone are automatically created as a record in my custom object.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Trigger on Lead object.

- You will need to write trigger on `After Update` event.
- In the trigger check for field `isConverted` value.
- If it is true it means that lead record is converted.
- And there you copy all fields value into the custom object and insert
  it.

You can not achieve it by declarative approach.

Comment: Thanks Ashwani,  I found the following code but I do not know how it works or how to implement it. Could you provide some insights?  Thank you.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87625/create-a-record-in-a-custom-object-when-a-lead-is-converted

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to do this using process builder. Search for process builder under the quick box and from there its pretty much straightforward.